# Web security question regarding an API

Tags: api, security, session-cookies

I'm building an API with no server-side authentication. A unique key (assume the key is very long and impossible to guess) will be generated for the session, but no cookie will be set on the client. The client could be a web browser with AJAX, a PHP script using CURL, or a desktop application. The normal transaction process I'm imagining will be:

#### Initial encounter

1. The client makes an initial request, calling a start_session method
2. The server generates a key and returns it along with some initial data
3. The client stores the key for later use (e.g. JavaScript sets a cookie with the key)

#### Next request

1. The client requests the server again, calling some set_data method, providing the original session key, as well as loads of private data such as a credit card number, information about legal cases, etc.
2. The server responds, and the responds with a success message

#### Another request

1. The client requests the server again, providing the original session key, and calling some get_data method
2. The server responds with all of the private data in some format (e.g. XML, JSON, etc)

A session key expires, if not used, in a 20 minutes, and **all API URIs will require SSL**.

**My concern / question is**: Do I need to be worried about whether the client has leaked the session key. Without authentication, I'm trusting that the original requester to keep the session key private. Is this common / safe practice?

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's impossible to guess?

Comment: What are you afraid of? What is in the attacker's control? Who / where are the clients? Who wrote the clients?

Comment: @SLaks - (regarding both sets of questions) 1) The session key is a combination of 2 different UUIDs from the Python library. It would take longer than 5 billion years with today's computers to "guess" the key (even using tricky math techniques). 2) I'm not afraid of anyone per se. Anyone who wants to use the API will be able to. If you have a website at `www.my-stupid-site-that-uses-an-api.com` and you write some AJAX code into your page (along with a proxy script for x-site AJAX), you could use the API, so I really have no control over who uses it. Is that OK, typically?

Comment: Are you asking whether arbitrary members of the public who use your API are sane?

Comment: @SLaks - I'm not asking if users are sane, or if it's possible that a user could put private data into their session, view their cookies, and finally put their session key on their blog's home page. I'm asking if it's a generally accepted safe practice to do this, or if there is any glaring reason I shouldn't (or perhaps technical security issues that one might easily overlook in this situation).

Comment: By `clients`, I mean the programmers who are clients of the library.

Comment: @SLaks - aside from your recommendation about warning clients, I can't trust whether the developers will have any skills at all. In fact, it's a given in this situation that a lot of them won't.

Comment: Then it depends how secure you want it to be.  A surprisingly large number of SSL sites contain non-SSL script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use HTTPS throughout, you're vulnerable to HTTP sniffing, *a la* Firesheep.

Eve, if you do use SSL, if the client page isn't SSL or contains any non-SSL Javascript (or non-SSL frames in the same domain), you're still vulnerable (and there's nothing you can do about it)

To answer your stated question, it completely depends on your situation.
**EDIT**: You should warn your clients (developers) in the documentation page to handle the key correctly.
Beyond that, it depends on the average skill level of the clients.
You should probably have a disclaimer of some sort (I am not a lawyer).

It's probably OK.

Comment: how does "it completely depends on your situation" answer a question?

Comment: @oro: It was telling you that your question as asked didn't have an answer.

Comment: thanks. The "Edit" section of your answer is the same conclusion I came to, but I wasn't sure if I was oversimplifying the issues. BTW, "a la" means "on the". If you wanted French, it would be "avec Firesheep".